# make an image in background page html in a responsive way

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to put an image in background of the page and in of course it must be in a responsive way
this is the html code :

```
<div > title </div>
<img src="/assets/img/image1.jpeg" />
```

and the css :

```
img {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the background-image propierty of the body

```
body {
  background-image: url("/assets/img/image1.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Marshall's solution is better if you want the image to cover the whole viewing area.

Although it would not be in the background, using your `<img/>` tag it would be like this:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div> title </div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
```

Comment: yes now it's responsive but the image must be in the background  so the title be on the image not before the image

Comment: Look at Marshall's solution.

Answer (score 1):

A background image for the *page* would be best placed on the `body` element — here's a simple example which uses the `background` shorthand:

```css
body {
  background: url('../relative/path/to/img/goes/here') no-repeat #paleblue;
}
```

Here, we've provided the image, an instruction that the image should not repeat (it will by default), and a 'fall-back' background colour — this is useful if, for example, the image fails to load.

There's more that can be done, here. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) for more details. Pay special attention to `background-size`, as you'll likely want to use either `cover` or `contain` depending on the image, screen size, etc. The [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for both is straightforward, but you can very easily swap one for another and back again in your code and see the (often obvious) effect each has.

Answer (score 0):

you can add background property to which container you want the background img is, if its body or any other container, also add to your img width and height property otherwise it will go beyond the container, you should add 100% if you want to cover the whole container.

```
  background-position:center center
```